# No route matches in show action- missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I looked at a few different answers similar to this question, but they all are getting the id passed into the params hash, it is just coming back as a nil value. I cant seem to get the id to be whitelisted and I cant figure out why.

This is my create and show action, also includes the params. I explicitly whitelisted id although I dont know if it is necessary.

```
  def show
    @board = Board.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @board = Board.new(board_params)

    if @board.save
      # flash[:notice] = 'You successfully created your post!'
      redirect_to board_path
    else
      render 'new'
      # flash[:danger] = 'One or more errors occurred when processing your post'
    end
  end

  private

  def board_params
    # params.require(:board).permit!
    params.require(:board).permit(:id, :project_name, :project_description, :postition_title, :project_url, :project_headquarters, :application_process)
  end
```

The output of my routes show action

`board GET    /boards/:id(.:format)             boards#show`

And the output of the params hash on board#create

`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"k+KKRhBk4Dnba1vxtFCanI2grfhNXFSgJpfEBLnhPdablfOsXRi1wBehPpM1qgx1pySrqxVHTeiwkneluXwRIQ==", "board"=>{"project_name"=>"sdf", "postition_title"=>"sdf", "project_headquarters"=>"sdf", "project_url"=>"fsd", "project_description"=>"dfs", "application_process"=>"dfs"}, "commit"=>"Create Board"}`

Can anyone see what I need to change in order to get the id passed in correctly?

Comment: You don't need to whitelist :id. Is the issue when you link to a boards show page, or are you also not able to go to /board/# by manually typing in the url?

Comment: also -- `redirect to @board` will take you to the show page.

Comment: im able to go to it manually. Also your solution worked, thank you, but do you know why redirecting to board_path doesnt work?

Comment: `boards_path` (pluralized) should take you to the board index page. and then if you want to go to a particular show page: `board_path(@board)`  < the id would be passed to know which board to show

Comment: thanks for the help @gwalshington

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Take :id out of params.

```
def show
end

def create
    @board = Board.new(board_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @board.save
        format.html { redirect_to @board, notice: 'Board was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @board }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @board.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

in `create` action...

**change ..**

```
redirect_to board_path
```

**to...**

```
redirect_to board_path(@board)
###OR
### this calls the show action
redirect_to @board
```